# Restore deleted products in Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento-1.8, product

I have deleted some products from Magento 1.8.1.0 to avoid duplicity   from a new import. But now all the associated alerts with deleted products are seem to be lost.

Usually a customer use to get an alert for already ordered item on website but it is not working the warning alert popup of 'item already ordered' is disappeared.

What are my chances to restore the product if there no backup?

Does deleting products deletes all the product_ids, mappings etc. from database?

Please help as soon as you can.

Comment: It might not possible to restore without backup.

Answer (score 2):

Its almost impossible to restore products if you dont have backup.

Does deleting products deletes all the product_ids, mappings etc. from database?    - YES (not sure about mapping)

Suggestion: Take help from hosting to restore the backup from past and you can ask hosting for only database backup. This is only seems possible in such situation.

Its always better to take backup before doing major change like import new products.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no previous backup of database and/or you don't have products backup in form of csv or xml or spreadsheet, then restoration is not possible at all.

You would need data in one of above formats to restore it.

Till Magento 1.9.x, there is no feature of soft delete (i.e. deleting products will still keep them for future restore).